# Is this a correct use case for the React useImperativeHandle hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning React hooks (and I'm fairly new to React), and was thinking through use cases for useImperativeHandle. I came up with a pretty useful scenario.

I do know that this can be accomplished without useImperativeHandle, but I think there are some advantages here.

What I don't know...

1. Have I 'discovered the obvious' and this isn't really useful? ... or
2. Is this bad form, or an anti-pattern?

My code is working- but I'm looking for input about best practices. Also, since there's a dearth of information right now about useImperativeHandle, this example that goes beyond an input ref might be useful to others.

I have a minimal example posted on Github if you want to play with it:
https://github.com/ericsolberg/react-uih-hook

Using markup similar to:

```
const App = props => {
  return (
    <Foo>
      <Bar>This is Bar 0</Bar>
      <Bar>This is Bar 1</Bar>
      <Bar>This is Bar 2</Bar>
    </Foo>
  );
};
```

What I've accomplished is:

1. Allow a parent component 'Foo' to provide state storage for it's children - so Foo can mount/dismount children yet allow them to restore state.
2. 'Bar' uses useImperativeHandle to provide a 'call-in' so Bar can veto being dismounted, in case it is doing something important.

As I noted, this works perfectly. In React, data and props flow down the tree, while callbacks flow up. This gives you a way, for specific scenarios, to call down the tree. Is it advisable?

Comment: Whole point of React is to take the burden of deciding when to mount or unmount from you. Otherwise I personally would still be writing jQuery UI widgets (which were much faster than React components btw). React is meant to be declarative as much as possible. `useImperativeHandle` is for those rare cases when you need, well, imperative API. On the other hand you can do whatever you like. That's, btw how React folks came with ReactJS idea in the first place.

Comment: Please, post relevant components, so the question could be fully understandable without navigating to external link. There are only few good use cases for imperative handles, and this isn't one of them. The code is a bit hard to understand, but in this case it seems that Bar needs to accept `hide` boolean prop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern: `Inject props into the children` without explicitly passing the props.

The idiomatic options are:

- pass props explicitly
- [use context](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)
- [Lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to be able to do the above 2
- [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html)

So if nothing simpler would be suitable for my business logic, I do something like following to avoid invisible tight coupling between Foo and Bar:

```
const App = () => (
  <Foo>
    {({selector, saveStateFactory}) => (<>
      <Bar state={selector(0)} saveState={saveStateFactory(0)} />
      <Bar state={selector(1)} saveState={saveStateFactory(1)} />
    </>)}
  </Foo>
)

const Foo = () => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(...)
  const selector = (id) => state[id]
  const saveStateFactory = (id) => {
    return (payload) => dispatch({type: id, payload})
  }
  // do something with whole state that cannot be done in App nor Bar
  return children({selector, saveStateFactory})
}
```